# Dynamically assign value to xpath expression in java

Tags: java, xpath, wsdl

I am trying to create gui dynamically from WSDL file by using java.
I need to retrieve the messages related with each operation.
For that i need to assign the XPath  expression value dynamically.
I assign the expression as follows

```
  String expression="/definitions/portType/operation[@name="+oper[i]+"]/*";
  NodeList msglist=    (NodeList)xpath.expressionxpath.compile(expression1).evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
  System.out.println("The Number of messages are"+msglist.getLength());
```

Here oper[i] is the array containing list of operation names.
But it is not working when I print the number of nodes in the msglist it always displays 0.
My WSDL file contains 2 child element for operation element.
Anyone can Helpme??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your XPath expression do the job; have you checked it? Try printing out the expression after the concat and checking it - it looks like you are missing quotes in the expression to me.

Comment: Yes i checked it it working it prints the desired result.

Comment: Could you post the generated expression?

Comment: When i try to evaluate the expression msglist contains nothing.I dont know what is the problem with it?

Comment: /definitions/portType/operation[@name=sayHello]/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, the pattern is:

```
/definitions/portType/opeation[@name=sayHello]/*
```

Quotes around the match string are missing. It should be:

```
/definitions/portType/opeation[@name="sayHello"]/*
```

So your pattern should be:

```
String expression="/definitions/portType/operation[@name=\""+oper[i]+"\"]/*";
```

It might be clearer to use a `MessageFormat` or `String.format`:

```
String expression=String.format("/definitions/portType/operation[@name=\"%s\"]/*", oper[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the missing quotes. However, you should try to avoid constructing XPath expressions by string concatenation, for at least three reasons:

- It's easy to make mistakes like the one you made
- There's a grave danger of leaving yourself open to code injection attacks
- Performance

Instead, take advantage of the fact that XPath expressions can contain variable references:

```
String expression="/definitions/portType/operation[@name=$param]/*";
```

and that you can bind a value to the variable when executing the expression. The JAXP mechanism for this (defining a VariableResolver) isn't especially elegant, but it's easy enough to use.